# draftjs init in selected DOM element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have layout builder which based in immutable.js structure display html elements. All is in ReactJS with Redux.

When I have rendered structure like

```
<div className="grid-x" data-draftjs-init="true">
      <div className="cell" data-draftjs-init="true"></div>
</div>
```

After double click on any element with attribute data-draftjs-init I'd like set there draftjs editor (my own component which use draft-js).

I know that I can get `ReactDOM.render(<Component />,event.target)` for dblclick event.
but then it will new app without access to store (Redux) of my application.

Does exists any way to set my component to double clicked html element but keep this element as part of my application with Redux store access?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<Component />,event.target) - component rendered that way can have access to redux store. You can either pass props to the Component: ReactDOM.render(<Component prop1={propFromStore} />,event.target) or make Component a connected component.

Comment: Yes but I can't update my storage from this component.

Comment: Why not? You can pass callback functions as props of this component. As i wrote earlier, the other method is connecting Component directly to the store either using @connect decorator or [connect HoC](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Comment: yes I can. I mean on this editor component level. Thanks for hint. I just solve it by:

I have immutable.js structure of rendered elements. After double click on some element I add to this element `isEditor` attribute and for each element with this attribute my components renderer add editor element as child.

Now I have full access to Redux store.